# Proving a Summation Equation by Induction

Tags: induction

> Prove this by induction:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n i(i!) = (n+1)!-1$$

So I wrote:

Base Case: $n=1$ so $1(1!) = 1$ and $(1+1)!-1 = 1$.

Let $n=k$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^ki(i!)=(k+1)!-1$$

$n=k+1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i(i!)=((k+1)+1)!-1$$

But I'm stuck here.  Also is there any easier way I can write out summation on stack exchange?  A format for writing it out on one line?  Or is my way preferred?

Comment: You can use common latex syntax to write mathematical formulas.  As an example `$\sum_1^n i\cdot i!$` is how I wrote the sum.  You can read more here: http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: $\sum_1^n i\cdot i!$  I see

Comment: Also, you can click edit on any answer or question to view their source (just make sure you discard your edit if you do that).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_1^n i\cdot i! = \sum_1^{n - 1} i\cdot i! + n\cdot n!
$$

Now plug in the formula for $\sum i\cdot i!$ for $n - 1$, add the next term and see if you get the correct formula for $n$:

$$
((n - 1) + 1)! - 1 + n\cdot n! = n! - 1 + n\cdot n! = (n + 1)n! - 1 
$$

That's the inductive step.  If the formula holds for $n - 1$ then it also holds for $n$.

Comment: So when dealing with factorials we use k-1 not k+1?

Comment: Also how did you make your notation so neat? Did you use alt-w and make it large font? Haha I'm just trying to figure out the best way.

Comment: You can do it either way.  You can use $n$ then prove the formula is still correct for $n + 1$.  I prefer going from $n - 1$ to $n$ because the final formula will be the exact formula (i.e. for $n$).  If you start with $n$, then the final result should be $(n + 2)! - 1$.

Comment: @adam - To see how a user did something, just $\color{grey}{edit}$ the question. Make sure to $\color{grey}{cancel}$ to get out. You can also right-click on a math equation and select **Show Math As/TeX Commands**, then paste into an answer box. Erase all of the text before you leave that page.